# SSIS Object Variable populated in Foreach Loop set to last row outside of the loop, cannot access whole array

Tags: c#, ssis

I have an SSIS package that will assemble dynamic SQL statement and execute on a different server with the results needing to be written back to the first server.
Because the SQL is created and passed in as a variable, a Foreach loop is used to run each instance.  The results are put into an Object Variable and This works fine.  If I put my script task in the Foreach loop itself, I can write the results back to the original server.  However- I would really like, for performance reasons, to get the insert out of the Foreach loop and read the result set / object variable to open one connection and write all the data at one go.  But when I pull the object doing the reading of the results and writing to the database out of the loop, it only write the last row of data, not all of them.
How can I get to all the rows in the result set outside of the Foreach loop?  Is there a pointer to the first row or something?  I can't imagine I'm the first person to need to do this but my search for answers has come up empty.  Or maybe I'm just under caffeinated.
[image]

Comment: To restate (also in the under-caffeinated crowd): As is, the foreach loop fires off individual commands. How can I concatenate all the individual queries (loop iterations) into a single query that you will use outside the loop builder?

Comment: Do you have a cluster?  Try "multiSubnetFailover=Yes".  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @billinkc - Not quite, apologies for not being clearer.  The Foreach Loop takes in an array that is in an Object type variable(User::CurrRuleSQL], extracts one column of it to use as a SQL statement to a target database, and the results of that query are stored in a different array-Object variable [User::ResultSet].  I want to be able to read the second object variable from outside the Foreach Loop.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @jdweng - cluster?  No, I don't think so. I wasn't looking at SQL Server solutions as the data is in an SSIS Object Variable.  Are you saying that the Object Variable can use the same keywords?

Comment: Oh, ok. So for every iteration, of `CurrRuleSQL`, a result set is written to `ResultSet` However, that's clobbering the results so you only get the last iteration of `CurrRuleSQL`'s results available outside of the loop?

Comment: If I'm on the right track here, then the ugly answer is you're going to have to use a script task and carry along your results. The Execute SQL Task is going to overwrite the value of your `ResultSet` every time it fires. A different approach would be to then shred the results of ResulSet and stuff that data into an actual table.

Comment: But that's exactly what complexes me - the exact same script task (I literally move it from inside the loop to outside) performs differently.  I did do a direct insert (Execute SQL Task) first as that seemed blindingly obvious at the time, but the data written was incomplete - the specific value I was getting in column 1 (or zero)  from the just executed SQL [CurrRuleSQL] was being lost.  So a script I tested *did* get the right results, Just requires a new connection every single row.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be simplified, if some conditions are met. Generally, SSIS is metadata centric, i.e. set of columns and its types. So, if each of SQL query you run returns the same set of columns, including column names, data types; then you can try the following approach:

1. In the *ForEach* loop, run SQL commands and store its results into an Object Variable.
2. Then - create a Data Flow task with a Script Component Source, fetching its rows from the step 1 Object Variable. Add the rows to some SQL table as you usually do; if needed - you can add some other data like SQL query text. The resulted rows can be added to some table as a DFT Destination.

How to use Object Variable as a data source - here are already [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585623/enumerating-recordset-in-dataflow-script-component-as-data-source) to this question